# Is there a tool on Ubuntu or Mac to monitor a program's CPU and I/O usage and I/O wait times?

Tags: io, cpu, cpu-usage, iowait

I want to determine if my application is IO or CPU bounded. Is there such a tool to determine how much of your application's run time is spent on CPU wait/IO wait/running on CPU etc.?
I am running my application from terminal.
I have heard there is such a tool for linux actually but I don't what is it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `mpstat` and `iostat` (I don't believe the former is available for OS X).

Comment: I think the tittle is a little misleading, sorry about that.
I actually want to monitor a certain program. 'mpstat' and 'iostat' gives system wide stats. I want to know how much of an application's run time is spent on CPU wait/IO wait/running on CPU etc.?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/5-system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu) is a list of the top 5 monitoring tools for ubuntu.  You can collect quite a bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the nmon.It can be used in most Linux environment.